# Update Fields On Form Based On Entries

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a bound form that has roughly 8 text boxes on it.  I am in some instances needing to subtract the value from textbox2 from the value in textbox1.  For example, my set-up is like so:

```
lblProfit     lblOTBilled
txtProfit     txtOTBilled
```

txtProfit is where the profit amount would be input, **BUT** if there is any OT billed, then I would need to use this formula

```
txtProfit = txtProfit - txtOTBilled
```

My issue is that both txtProfit and txtOTBilled are bound fields so I am not quite sure how to go about setting this up.

In Access 2013 how would I do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need an additional textbox:

```
txtProfitCalculated
```

and control source for this:

```
=[txtProfit]-Nz([txtOTBilled],0)
```

Comment: How would I write the value of txtProfitCalculated back to my table?

Comment: Update the recordset. But it sounds like you need to rethink the form layout and the interaction with the user.

Comment: I am converting an Excel worksheet to an access form so the data is in a table (easy to query).  This issue stems from the user being so acclimated to Excel performing the calculation that I am being forced to have the Access form do the same.  Visually it is easy to display this, but updating the table to display the same results is where the issue lies.

Comment: Since it is a bound form, you can update fields directly. But Access is not Excel.